# Compiling Recipe Array Keys and Values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of recipes. Each recipe contains an array of ingredients:

```
[Waffle] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [amount] =>  1
                    [measurement] => large
                    [ingredient] => egg 
                    [grocery] => dairy
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [amount] =>  1
                    [measurement] => cup
                    [ingredient] => milk 
                    [grocery] => dairy
                )

        )

[Pancake] => Array
        (

            [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [amount] =>  1
                        [measurement] => large
                        [ingredient] => egg
                        [grocery] => dairy
                    )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [amount] =>  1
                    [measurement] => tablespoon
                    [ingredient] => maple syrup
                    [grocery] => pantry
                )

        )
```

I want to create a grocery list of all ingredients, compiling the amounts by ingredient and measurement, and ordered according to the grocery aisle.

So, given the above, it would output something like:

```
DAIRY

2 large eggs
1 cup milk

PANTRY

1 tablespoon maple syrup
```

Any help you can give writing a function to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything already? or do you expect someone to do it all for you?

Comment: I think they'd look at me funny in the store if I asked for 2 large eggs, a cup of milk, and a tablespoon of maple syrup.  ;)  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was hoping someone had done something like this before and had a suggestion for how to approach it since it is pretty complicated.

I thought of trying to merge the arrays, but I run into problems because I need to get the sum of the amounts. I'm also running into issues where "egg" is treated as a separate ingredient than "eggs."

I don't expect someone to write the whole solution for me, but some ideas on how to do this efficiently are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the names of ingredients and scale of measurements varied so greatly, I ended up just grouping ingredients by grocery aisle and not combining the measurements.

I looped through arrays to build additional array sets containing the necessary data I needed to output the groups as needed.

I could have gone further and created a conversion table, then converted each measurement to standard scale, and then added the total of ingredients, but, fortunately, this isn't necessary at the moment.